# Join three tables on id

Tags: sql

Hej,

I can't quite wrap my head around this problem...

I have three tables I need to join.

**Table 'room'**

```
name   | desccription
------ | -------------
room 1 | desccription 
room 2 | desccription 
room 3 | desccription 
room 4 | desccription 
room 5 | desccription
```

**Table 'sensor'**

With foreign key room_name and there can be multiple sensors in one room.

```
id | room_name | name 
-- | --------- | --------
1  | room 1    | sensor 1
2  | room 1    | sensor 2
3  | room 1    | sensor 3
4  | room 2    | sensor 4
5  | room 3    | sensor 5
6  | room 4    | sensor 6
```

**Table 'actor'**

With foreign key room_name and there can be multiple actors in one room.

```
id | room_name | name 
-- | --------- | --------
1  | room 1    | actor 1
2  | room 2    | actor 2
3  | room 2    | actor 3
4  | room 4    | actor 4
5  | room 4    | actor 5
6  | room 4    | actor 6
```

**As a result I would like something like this**

```
room.name | sensor.name | actor.name 
--------- | ----------- | -----------
room 1    | sensor 1    | NULL
room 1    | sensor 2    | NULL
room 1    | sensor 3    | NULL
room 1    | NULL        | actor 1
room 2    | sensor 4    | NULL
room 2    | NULL        | actor 2
room 2    | NULL        | actor 3
room 3    | sensor 5    | NULL
room 4    | sensor 6    | NULL
room 4    | NULL        | actor 4
room 4    | NULL        | actor 5
room 4    | NULL        | actor 6
room 5    | NULL        | NULL
```

My attempt was to join those three tables and group them by room_name, but this only gives the first sensor or actor (depending on NULL values) and does not concatenate those values. In the long run, concatenation wouldn't be too good to work with anyway, so I would prefer the shown result above.

When I try to use `UNION` on tables sensor and actor, I can't distinguish sensor and actor names anymore. Furthermore I won't get rooms without any sensors and actors in the result anymore. I suppose it's not possible to give column names like `sensor_name`.

```
SELECT room.name AS room_name, sensor.name AS sensor_name
FROM room INNER JOIN sensor ON room.name = sensor.room_name
UNION
SELECT room.name AS room_name, actor.name AS actor_name
FROM room INNER JOIN actor ON room.name = actor.room_name
```

You can find a figurative represantation here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlqSU.jpg
(I'm not allowed to post pictures yet).

Do you have any suggestions? Any help or hint would be appreciatet!
(I am not that well versed yet with SQL).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were doing fine, you just need to add another column to identify them :

```
SELECT room.name AS room_name, sensor.name AS sensor_name, NULL as actor_name
FROM room 
INNER JOIN sensor
  ON room.name = sensor.room_name
UNION
SELECT room.name AS room_name, NULL as sensor_name,actor.name AS actor_name
FROM room 
INNER JOIN actor 
  ON room.name = actor.room_name
```

Though by your result set I suspect you are looking for a `LEFT JOIN` and not an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I already spend hours to solve this... `NULL AS` solved the problem and you are absolutely right about using a `LEFT JOIN` instead :)